# How can ScalaMeter chain configuration

Tags: scala, scalameter

I'm quite confusing on how can ScalaMeter chain configuration like this

```
val standardConfig = config(
  Key.exec.minWarmupRuns -> 5,
  Key.exec.maxWarmupRuns -> 10,
  Key.exec.benchRuns -> 10,
  Key.verbose -> true
) withWarmer(new Warmer.Default)
```

The first `config(...)` expression returns `MeasureBuilder[T, U]` type, this I understand.

However, how can we chain the second expression `withWarmer(new Warmer.Default)` which also returns `MeasureBuilder` type.

At first, I guess that `MeasureBuilder` type implement apply method that allow us to do this, but at the last step before measuring the performance of a piece of code we need

```
val partime = standardConfig measure {
  ...
}
```

where `measure { ... }` return `Quantity[U]` type which is not `MeasureBuilder`.

So, How can ScalaMeter configuration chain the expression like that?

Comment: The space between `config(..)` and `withWarmer` is just an alternative syntax to the dotted one, similar to what would be `config(..).withWarmer(..)`

Comment: You should change your `measure` so that it returns the Builder. Or better yet, create a helper `withMeasure` that delegates to the existing implementation and then return to the Builder. You could add it using an implicit if `MeasureBuilder` is a third party type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please first note that [`config`](https://github.com/scalameter/scalameter/blob/e0c72b3abc9bab13b39fe226a83a0e79eec89ee6/scalameter-core/src/main/scala/org/scalameter/MeasureBuilder.scala#L17) method is exposed after imporing:

```
import org.scalameter.config
```

This is because it is declared on the [companion object](https://github.com/scalameter/scalameter/blob/e0c72b3abc9bab13b39fe226a83a0e79eec89ee6/scalameter-core/src/main/scala/org/scalameter/package.scala#L12) in the package level:

```
package object scalameter extends MeasureBuilder[Unit, Double](
```

Therefore when you declare `val standardConfig = config(...)` you get `MeasureBuilder[Unit, Double]`

Afterwards, the class `MeasureBuilder` exposes a method [`withWarmer`](https://github.com/scalameter/scalameter/blob/e0c72b3abc9bab13b39fe226a83a0e79eec89ee6/scalameter-core/src/main/scala/org/scalameter/MeasureBuilder.scala#L20), which is actually called, and returns a `MeasureBuilder[Unit, Double]`, with both configuration and warmer applied.

`MeasureBuilder` exposes a method [`measure`](https://github.com/scalameter/scalameter/blob/e0c72b3abc9bab13b39fe226a83a0e79eec89ee6/scalameter-core/src/main/scala/org/scalameter/MeasureBuilder.scala#L63):

```
def measure[S](b: =>S): Quantity[U] = measured(b)._2
```

which returns `Quantity[Double]` in your example.